# bash echo executes command instead of printing it

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I have simple bash command that I need to put in shell:

```
 `for f in $(ls); do echo "File -> $f"; done`
```

What I get is:

```
-bash: File: command not found
```

I don't understand why bash is trying to execute echo statement instead of printing it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The backticks cause the execution.  The command inside the backtiks outputs a string, and the backticks execute that string as a command.

Answer (score 3):

You [should'nt be](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs) really parsing `ls` for this. Do something like:

```
for f in *; do echo "File -> $f"; done
```

For directories:

```
for i in *; do if [ -d $i ]; then  echo "File -> $i"; fi ; done
```

or

```
find . -type d -exec echo '{}' \;
```

Comment: what if I want to list only directories? Using my script I can add -d, I don't know how to modify yours.

Comment: The link for http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs gets you a +1 :). Just realised you'd already added it, so deleted the comment suggesting it's addition.

Comment: Thanks @Samveen, I should have emphasized the link in a better way.

Answer (score 2):

Why not `$(find . -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -type d ! -name index -printf '%f/* ')`?

- no looping shell code
- no escaping issues on the input side
- portable

Comment: Because `a=""; for f in $(ls -d -- */); do if [[ "$f" != "index/" ]]; then a="$a$f* "; fi done; echo "$a";` and because I'm bash newbie so maybe even that can be written in a simpler way.

Comment: `find` has pattern checking. I encourage you to take a look at its manual page, if you intend to write more shell scripts looking for files. I'm going to edit my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I used it in `sh` mode, works fine. Remove the backsticks at the start and at the end of command, and it will work.